# Factorization of exponents in Maxima

Tags: maxima

I would like Maxima to perform `factor` in exponents of all exponentials in my expression.

For example,

```
(%i1) F: exp(-(a + b)^2) + exp(-(c + d)^2)$
(%i2) G: expand(F);
```

produces

```
                       2             2         2             2
                   (- d ) - 2 c d - c      (- b ) - 2 a b - a
(%o2)            %e                    + %e
```

but none of `factor(G)`, `radcan(G)` or `gcfac(G)` takes me back to the original expression `F`. Is there a way how to convert `G` to `F`?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
(%i32) map(lambda([z], scanmap(factor,z)), G);

                                     2              2
                            - (d + c)      - (b + a)
(%o32)                    %e           + %e
```

I figured this out by using `scanmap` on the first term, and then using
`map` to do this for each of the terms in `G`.

Not sure how general this approach is.